# Hiding 'Browse' and 'Page' based on the permissions in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am using sharepoint 2013. I want to hide 'Browse' and 'Page' options based on permissions.

I tried with css, but it hides for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this with JavaScript, but it's pretty messy.  You have to get current user, determine permission level and then take action based on that to set your CSS.

See this SO Question here for how to check if user belongs to a group:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m

To check for permissions for an object you can use something like below.  Here we are checking the current web to see if the user has manageweb permissions.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
var web = context.get_web();    

var baseper = new SP.BasePermissions();    
baseper.set(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb)   
var permission = web.doesUserHavePermissions(baseper)

ctx.executeQueryAsync(    
     function(){     
          if(permission.get_value()){
             //User has permissions
          }else{
            //user does not have permissions add your CSS to hide elements here
          }
        },    
     function(a,b){    
         //Error;    
 }

);
```

List of base permissions are here on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx

Additionally you can customize the master page.  Wrap the elements you want to hide with a security timming control:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat=”server” Permissions=”DeleteListItems”>

Content Here is trimmed

</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

The problem with this is it will hide the entire ribbon (as you won't get access to just the "page" element in this manner, as it's rendered as part of the ribbon.